# Convert first index in array to int

Tags: c#

I have a list of strings called parentRows which contains strings that look like this:

```
"176,c-4454"
"177,c-34324"
```

I've used `.split(',')` to put them in a `string[]`

```
var arr = parentRow.Split(',');
```

because essentially what I want is that when I loop through the list, if the user input matches `arr[1]`, then I want to convert `arr[0]` to an `int` and store it in the user's information.

Code snippet:

```cs
if (p.ParentCode != "")
{                   
    foreach(var parentRow in parentRows)
    {
        var arr = parentRow.Split(',');
                           
        if(arr[1] == p.ParentCode)
        {
            int asInt = arr[0].Select(s => int.Parse(s));
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see I've tried  `int asInt = arr[0].Select(s => int.Parse(s));`
but I just get the error

`"Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'System.ReadOnlySpan<char>"`

How would one go about achieving what I want?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you just want to parse element 0 (`arr[0]`)

```
int value =  int.Parse(arr[0])
```

The long story is `SomeString.Select` *projects* a `string` to an *array* of `char`, and `int.Parse` has an overload for `ReadOnlySpan`. The compiler assumes through the *overload resolution* that is the best fit for what want to do. Which is what the error is telling you

> "Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to
> 'System.ReadOnlySpan"

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
if(! string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.ParentCode) )
{
    var l = parentRows
      .Select(r => r.Split(','))               // split every item in array by comma
      .Where(r => r[1] == p.ParentCode)        // select only those, which second element matches the code
      .Select(r => int.Parse(r[0])).ToArray(); // select only first element of slpitted string casting it to int
}
```